# How can I print a pyramid shape using a nested loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-loops

I want to produce a similar shape to the above using a nested loop. Can anyone here help me with that?

```py
print('        #')
print('       ###')
print('      ####')
print('     #####')
print('    #######')
print('   #########')
print('  ###########')
print(' ############')
print('###############')


for x in range(0, 10):
    print(' #')
```

Comment: @PatrickArtner Where are you seeing flag on a pole shape? If I go to the revision history and click the "edit" link on OP's original version, this is what I see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeNmA.png The only spacing/layout change I can see is the one you made.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how-to-print-a-pyramid-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61578101/how-to-print-a-pyramid-in-python)

Comment: @Tyler  Original post by the autor: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/68035830/1 - all # are prefixed by 1 space in the `print(...)` statements ?

Comment: @PatrickArtner The link you are sharing does not have any markdown view visible. Go to the [revisions page](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68035830/revisions), scroll to the bottom, and click "edit" on the original version by OP to see their intended markdown. Multiple spaces in non-code are ignored by the browser when rendering, so in non-code it *looks* like one space.

Comment: Ouch sorry for my confusion then

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code for you.

Code for # program using nested loop

```
def triangle(n):
    k = n - 1
    for i in range(0, n):
        for j in range(0, k):
            print(end=" ")
        k = k - 1
        for j in range(0, i+1):
            print("# ", end="")
        print("\r")
n = 10
triangle(n)
```

For each line-number (`i`-th line) we need to print `n-(i+1)` spaces followed by `i+1` `#`. Our `for i in range(0,n):` delivers `i` from 0 to n-1. `k` is used to easier keep track of needed spaces.

For 10 the output is:

```
         #
        # #
       # # #
      # # # #
     # # # # #
    # # # # # #
   # # # # # # #
  # # # # # # # #
 # # # # # # # # #
# # # # # # # # # #
```

Comment: -1 . This is not a code-provider website. You should at least add a description of what the code does. Also, the user did not show any code he tried, so replying to this question is out of the scope of StackOverflow.

Comment: Today I learned that the display is not to be trusted, sorry for my confusion.

Comment: @Neb description was done. comment obsolete?

Comment: @Neb Providing code is not mandatory for a question to be considered on-topic.